# Azure synapse analytics- synapse link authentication

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

The synapse link for Dataverse is running fine when the storage account access key is disabled. We can able to create new records, there is no problem here.
But it fails to set up a new synapse link for Dataverse when the storage account key is disabled. Has anyone seen this issue before?

expecting synapse link to work when the storage account access key is disabled

Answer (score 1):

As per my analysis looks like the Storage account key access should be enabled at the time of Synapse link creation and once it is created successfully, then you can disable the storage access key and the behavior should be similar to that your existing Synapse link service.

Answer (score 0):

This is now in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-synapse#prerequisites):

> Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2: You must have an Azure Data Lake Storage
> Gen2 account and Owner and Storage Blob Data Contributor role access.
> Your storage account must enable Hierarchical namespace for both
> initial setup and delta sync. **Allow storage account key access is
> required only for the initial setup**.